# Python Bottle SSE

Tags: python, bottle, server-sent-events

I'm trying to get Server Sent Events to work from Python, so I found a little demo code and to my surprise, it only partly works and I can't figure out why.  I got the code from [here](https://gist.github.com/werediver/4358735) and put in just a couple little changes so I could see what was working (I included a print statement, an import statement which they clearly forgot, and cleaned up their HTML to something I could read a little easier). It now looks like this:

```
# Bottle requires gevent.monkey.patch_all() even if you don't like it.
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
from gevent import sleep

from bottle import get, post, request, response
from bottle import GeventServer, run
import time


sse_test_page = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js "></script>
        <script>
            var es = new EventSource("/stream");
            es.onmessage = function(e) {
                document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = e.data;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Server Sent Events Demo</h1>
        <p id="log">Response Area</p>
    </body>
</html>
"""


@get('/')
def index():
    return sse_test_page


@get('/stream')
def stream():
    # "Using server-sent events"
    # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events
    # "Stream updates with server-sent events"
    # http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

    response.content_type  = 'text/event-stream'
    response.cache_control = 'no-cache'

    # Set client-side auto-reconnect timeout, ms.
    yield 'retry: 100\n\n'

    n = 1

    # Keep connection alive no more then... (s)
    end = time.time() + 60
    while time.time() < end:
        yield 'data: %i\n\n' % n
        print n
        n += 1
        sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(server=GeventServer, port = 21000)
```

So here's what ends up happening: I can see the original header and paragraph on the website, but response area never changes.  On the python side, it prints `n` once per second, but I never see that change on the web page. I get the feeling that I just lack a fundamental understanding of what I'm trying to do but I can't find anything missing.

I'm running Python 2.7, windows 7, chrome 43.0.2357.81 m.

**EDIT:** I got rid of the extra quotation mark.  Now it only seems to update when it gets to 60 (which I guess is better than not at all...)
Why would it wait until the end of the function to send the event?

Answer (score 3):

You've got 2 sets of quotes after p id="log""

Comment: WOW I can't believe I didn't notice that...ok that's closer! So, once it gets to 60 it essentially restarts.  At that point, "Response Area" changes to 60, but it misses all the other numbers in between.  Why is it waiting so long to update?